# Strange rendering in Direct3D 10

Tags: directx, shaders, 3d-meshes, directx10

I'm writing an application which renders graphics on the screen. The application can switch between Direct3D9 and Direct3D10 graphics modules (I wrote DLLs that wrap both D3D9 and D3D10). When trying to render a test mesh (a torus which comes as a stock mesh in D3DX9 and in DXUT library you can find in DirectX10 samples), Direct3D10 module behaves rather weird. Here's what I get.

D3D9:
[image: Torus rendered by D3D9 module.]

D3D10:
[image: Torus rendered by D3D10 module]

The view, projection and world matrices are the same for both cases. The only thing that differs is the device initialization code, and the HLSL effect files (for simplicity I only apply ambient colors and don't use advanced lighting, texturing etc). Can this be because of wrong device initialization or because of bad shaders? I would appreciate any hint. I can post any code pieces by request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be the wrong matrix order, eg passing row major when the shader expects column major or vice vesa. Try if swapping the order of the operants in your mul() calls fixes this.

Comment: OK, I'll try that. Though I'm sure the multiplication order is unchanged across D3D9 and D3D10 versions.

Comment: You can specify a matrix packing when compiling the effect: [D3DXSHADER Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205441(v=vs.85).aspx) Perhaps the default did change.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: It definitely looks like a transposed projection matrix. You could debug this using PIX.

Comment: After some testing I can definitely say that the reason is the .fx file/the matrix computations in it. When I disable the shader program, I can successfully output text with ID3DXFont, but when I enable it, even the text gets kind of warped...

Comment: Without sharing the relevant code it's going to be hard to help you beyond that (assuming you haven't figured it out already).

Comment: Can you post the vertex/pixel shaders and input layouts? Some of the input element semantics have changed between D3D9 and 10/11 I believe

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for trying to help. I figured it out. The reason for that was because somehow the **position** variable in vertex shader had garbage in its **w** component. After assigning 1.0f to that the shader worked as expected.